# 550 Filename invalid

Tags: scripting, ftp, error-handling

I have a script that generate a log and in the end of the script i move the log to a windows server. The connection between the 2 servers is fine, if i try to send the files manually it works good.

Script and logs are in 2 different location.
My script is like below:

```
LOGFILE=/home/logs/monitor_sync_FM2.log
HOST='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
USER='FTPUser'
PASSWD='Password'


ftp -n $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASSWD
binary
prompt
mput $LOGFILE
quit
EOF
exit 0
```

but when i run the script i get the error:

```
Filename invalid
```

Can anyone please tell me if i'm missing something in my script? Thanks

Comment: Try quoting the value of LOGFILE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write the file to the path `/home/logs/monitor_sync_FM2.log` on the remote server (ie windows).  550 Filename invalid indicates that `/home/logs` does not exist on the remote server.  What you want to do is this:

```
LOGFILE=monitor_sync_FM2.log
HOST='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
USER='FTPUser'
PASSWD='Password'

cd /home/logs/
ftp -n $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASSWD
binary
prompt
mput $LOGFILE
quit
EOF
exit 0
```

Comment: hi @Outurnate, sorry i should be clearer, the log is generated on unix machine, and move it from unix to windows.

Comment: right, I understand that.  That's why you can't save to `/home/logs/monitor_sync_FM2.log` on the windows machine.  `mput` takes the destination path - not the source

Comment: Many thanks, you opened my eyes and clarify my issue, i added a "lcd /home/logs" before the mput and now everything works as should be. Many thanks again

Comment: happy to help!  Make sure to mark the answer as well to assist future users